# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045]

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'XXXXX'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I created this user with appropriate privileges in phpMyAdmin.

I've read [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)  and have questions:

1) Will the error message be the same if I have a user name but the password is different or will it give me a different error (methinks the error is the same regardless) but need to be sure.

2) Could this issue have anything whatsoever to do with too little hard drive space?

3) `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON`XXXXXXX_%`.* TO 'XXXXXXX'@'localhost'WITH GRANT OPTION;`
I ran this query, this user has full privleges:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `XXXXXXX_%` . * FROM  'XXXXXXX'@'localhost';

REVOKE GRANT OPTION ON  `XXXXXXX_%` . * FROM  'XXXXXXX'@'localhost';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `XXXXXXX_%` . * TO  'XXXXXXX'@'localhost';
```

Was this the right thing to do?

4) I have access to the app/etc/local.xml file, what - if anything should I check in there to see if I'm on the right track? I see the user name appropriately listed there but...
I cannot seem to find a reference to the livedb for dbname anywhere in phpMyAdmin, where could I look?

```
 <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[XXXXXXX]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXX]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[XXXXX_livedb]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by comparing the password for the user.

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'XXXXX' AND Host = 'localhost' ;
```

Make sure that row exists, and the `plugin` column shows `mysql_native_password` and `password_expired` shows `N`.

If all of that is okay, then compare the password values. To get a hash value to compare, you can run this:

```
 SELECT PASSWORD('mysecret')
```

And then compare the returned value to the value stored in the `Password` column of the row in the `mysql.user` table. If the hash values are identical, then 'mysecret' is a valid password for that user.

---

If that specific row doesn't exist in the `mysql.user` table, note that an anonymous user at localhost (`''@localhost`) will take precedence over a `XXXXX@'%'` account.  (And this is kind of confusing to the uninitiated.)

In MySQL, a user is identified by two things: `User` and `Host`.  When you login to MySQL, the MySQL server has a specific order it looks for a matching row in the `mysql.user` table. First, it looks for an *exact* match on user and host...

`User='XXXXX' Host='localhost'`

If found, that's the user... it will check the password (or whatever authentication mechanism, to see if connection is allowed.) If no match is found, then MySQL server checks for an anonymous user

`User='' Host='localhost'`

And if no match is found there, then it will check:

`User='XXXXX' Host='%'`

Comment: Thank you Woking on this

Comment: @walterwhite: I hesitate to ask this, but based on your handle... this isn't for a wickedly profitable chemistry project ala Breaking Bad... is it? (I suppose not. If it was, your handle would be Heisenberg, wouldn't it.)